# Electret microphone amplifier to control an LED strip

Tags: led-strip, microphone, frequency-measurement

First sorry about my English. So my problem is so simple but I can't figure it out. I have a frequency to voltage circuit which is working perfectly but I want to control it by the voice.

https://youtu.be/lU1GVVU9gLU

I put a link here to show how I want it. The circuit is the same. I just need a microphone and an amplifier but I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm stuck on my phone (no electricity to the home for another week or so) so I'm not going to view YouTube videos. That said, there is a relatively simple circuit for externally powered electret microphones that should boost things to about line level: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/546030/38098) . See near the very top, there. You will need to decide if it is appropriate, though.

Comment: You may like this project. https://learn.adafruit.com/led-ampli-tie/overview

Comment: @jonk are you a Texan?  Condolences on the power outage hope you're OK.

Comment: @KH Not Texan. Though they are in the news more. I'm in Oregon. Our power system is part of the western grid, but our geography includes everything from sea level rising to 11,200' elevation over just a few miles of distance. The Rockies are pitiful by comparison when looking at rapid elevation change. So it's a different situation, though similar in magnitude of those affected in Texas. It's also taking us longer to recover. Because I live in a rainforest, they will have to helicopter in my power poles and then string in wire. This will be the longest outage in my life here -- 65 years.

Comment: @Jonk wow that's roughin' it.  I guess it's similar to what people in western AB and BC must have to do up here in Canada, but I hope you weather it well.  I hope we get to eventually see whether the cost savings in not having a winterized grid in Texas exceed the cost of even this one disaster.  I guess I'm off topic though.  Thanks for the answer and hope you stay comfortable.

Comment: @KH My water comes from a deep well that sits 40 m below my house. Without power, there's no water. With over a half meter of snow and ice, couldn't leave to go anywhere, either. Luckily, we had sufficient storage of fresh water and food supplies to last at least this long. We have 5000 liters of kerosene to supply the tractors and about 20 cord of wood stored up. So I'm in pretty good shape. However, we've decided to add a diesel generator and battery storage to the home, this summer. We should have enough generation capacity to supply us for two months, then.